# All table entries in knitr, markdown numbered

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm trying to learn the specs of knitr and r markdown (R_64 3.2.3). In trying to assemble a table, regardless of approach, all resulting entries in the table, whether headers or row or columns, are sequentially numbered. For example, the following:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Untitled@Untitled"
date: "19 August 2016"
output: word_document
---

```{r test, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(pander)
x<-matrix(NA,ncol=4,nrow=3)
x[1,]<-c(2,3,4,5)
x[2,]<-c(8,8,8,8)
x[3,]<-c(4,7,3,2)
colnames(x)<-c("CSEO","SSEO","EYKT","Global")
```

```{r pander, echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE, message=FALSE, error=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
panderOptions("digits", 2)
pander(x)
```
````

produces a table when knitted to a Word document that looks like this -

```
1.  CSEO    2.  SSEO    3.  EYKT    4.  Global
5.  2   6.  3   7.  4   8.  5
9.  8   10. 8   11. 8   12. 8
13. 4   14. 7   15. 3   16. 2
```

and a simple expression like this:

```
CSEO | SSEO | EYKT | Global  
-----|------|------|-------  
2    | 3    | 4    | 5  
8    | 8    | 8    | 8    
4    | 7    | 3    | 1
```

produces this:

```
1.  CSEO    2.  SSEO    3.  EYKT    4.  Global
5.  2   6.  3   7.  4   8.  5
9.  8   10. 8   11. 8   12. 8
13. 4   14. 7   15. 3   16. 1
```

I'm assuming I have a dependency configuration problem or am missing a package or somesuch, as the outputs have the same error (all entries are numbered) even though using different calls, but I've not been able to resolve it.

Comment: hi @kvk, i am unable to replicate your problem (i.e. unnecessary numbering of entries).

Comment: Chinsoon - that reinforces the idea that I have a package or dependency issue, if it works fine for you. Thanks for testing it.

Comment: fyi, i am using 64bit R 3.3.0 and `pander_0.6.0`